# Swift5 Text Field Integers from User Input

Tags: swiftui, textfield, swift5

Using Swift5. UI (not storyboard), being new to Xcode, after retrieving Text Field STRING from user, 1) how do I CONVERT the string to an integer so that I can perform math calculations from user responses to multiple text fields?.. and 2) where does the code go?

Comment: Show your code and what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
    @State private var textfieldInput = ""
    var Int1: Int {
    return Int(textfieldInput) ?? 0 // String to Int conversion is always return optional.
    }

    //some code
    TextField("Text", text: $textfieldInput)
```

2)
How shall wie tell, if we don't know your code? But I tried my best above to show the concept.

Comment: `Int1` should not be a `@State` var, as it depends wholly on `textfieldInput`. I'd recommend it being a computed property instead

Answer (score 1):

In the following app, `resultString` is the computed property that convert string to Int. This expression is an Optional since String can be anything when we try.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num: Int = 0
    @State private var text: String = "0"
    private var resultInt: Int {
        return self.num*self.num
    }
    private var resultString: String {
        if let num = Int(self.text) { // Here it convert the string to an integer
            return String(num*num)
        }
        return "0"
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("String Number",text: self.$text)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField("Int Number", value: self.$num, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Spacer()
            Text("Square is \(self.resultInt)").font(.title)
            Text("Square is \(self.resultString)").font(.title)
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

@rick-h comment down if you need clarification

Comment: Have got it all working now....many thanks to those of you who contributed solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, (I'm really new at this) for not including my code earlier. Hope this helps.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var xUSERNAME: String = ""
    @State var xUSERNAME2: String = ""
    @State var xMATH: Int = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Hello World!")
            TextField("Enter User Name...", text: $xUSERNAME)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Text("YOUR USER NAME: \(xUSERNAME)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        
            TextField("Enter User Name...", text: $xUSERNAME2)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Text("YOUR USER NAME: \(xUSERNAME2)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text("YOUR USER NAME: \(xUSERNAME)\(xUSERNAME2)")
            Text("\(xUSERNAME)")
        }.padding()   
    }
}
```